# Running PHPunit in Terminal as "vendor/bin/phpunit" shows Warning No tests found in class

Tags: laravel, phpunit

when running `vendor/bin/phpunit`  i received this error

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit
```

> PHPUnit 7.5.12 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> .W                                                                  2
>   / 2 (100%)
>
> Time: 113 ms, Memory: 12.00 MB
>
> There was 1 warning:
>
> 1) Warning No tests found in class

**and Then Tried reinstalling composer, and php unit to current version**

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit
```

> PHPUnit 7.5.12 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> .W                                                                  2
>   / 2 (100%)
>
> Time: 113 ms, Memory: 12.00 MB
>
> There was 1 warning:
>
> 1) Warning No tests found in class
>
> Should show test successful

Comment: How is your file name and class named, please also inlcude sample class with one single test

Comment: forgot to put the /** @test */ before the tests! Thank you, answered my question

Comment: you can also name your test function with test like relation_test and it will work

Comment: @MartinHenriksen: but the `test` must be at the beginning of the test method name, not at then end, mustn't it?

Comment: @hakre yes i forgot, mixed it up with a place where we used /** (at)test **/ notation

Answer (score 1):

Try This in your Testing Class:

```
/** @test **/
function your_test_func(){
   // assertion 
}
```

Compare with the [Phpunit Documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.test) which give the following description of the **`@test`** annotation:

> ### @test
>
> As an alternative to prefixing your test method names with `test`, you can use the `@test` annotation in a method's DocBlock to mark it as a test method.
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @test
>  */
> public function initialBalanceShouldBe0()
> {
>     $this->assertEquals(0, $this->ba->getBalance());
> }
> ```